# configure index format of neomutt

Tags: mutt, neomutt

I am using neomutt and configure the way the senders name is displayed.
(not altering display name in outgoing mails)

`index_format` can do that, and it's defeault is

```
%4C %Z %{%b %d} %-15.15L (%?l?%4l&%4c?) %s
```

`L` means author's name.

I like to control author's name and
want that nickname I've set with alias will be displayed.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `reverse_alias` and define aliases for people You want to display with nickname. This will affect displaying on index only as You want - no changes in pager or anywhere else.

Example:

```
set reverse_alias = yes

alias boss My boss <my.boss@exmaple.org>
```

reverse_alias in docs: [neomutt](https://neomutt.org/guide/reference#3-324-%C2%A0reverse_alias), [mutt](http://mutt.org/doc/manual/#reverse-alias)

Comment: thanks. In addition, for utf-8 names, `set config_charset = "utf-8"` was needed, and nickname is needed to be quoted.